# Is this snprintf method a safe way to copy strings?

Tags: c, string, char, overflow, strcpy

I need your advice. I use this way to copy strings knowing a max size to not go over but some of these strings don't end with a null terminator. It's just a snippet.

```
void my_strcpy(char* dest, const char* src, const size_t max_size)
{
    snprintf(dest, max_size, "%.*s", max_size - 1, src);
}
```

Is there a safer method? `strlcpy`? (I've not handled errors here.)

Comment: Not safe: `*` expects an `int`.  Try `snprintf(dest, max_size, "%.*s", (int)(max_size - 1), src);`

Comment: `strlcpy()` is a non-standard function. `strncpy()` is less safe than `snprintf()` because it is not guaranteed to nul-terminate the string. You pass the *actual* buffer size to `snprintf()`.

Comment: "but some of these strings don't end by a null terminator." is a contradiction in C terms.  The C library defines _string_ as containing a _null character_.  Perhaps better as "but some of these character arrays ...."

Comment: If they don't end in a nul, you can't pass them to the string handling functions. Those with length restrictions are to guard the *destination* buffer, not to limit the source. Use `memcpy` for that.

Comment: @WeatherVane `snprintf(dest, max_size, "%.*s"...` here is not a _string_ function.  OP's use here is somewhat OK as `"%.*s"` matches a character array pointer.

Comment: If you know the size and have sanitized the input then the correct way to copy strings is `strcpy` or `memcpy`. Don't mix up input sanitation with copying, those are two separate things.

Answer (score 1):

OP's use looks OK - perhaps a bit pedantic with a size limit and *precision*.

`"%.*s"` tolerates a pointer to a *character array* with no *null character*.  Copying will limit to the precision or the *null character*, whichever is first.

Resultant `dest[]` should never be not null-character terminated with valid arguments.

I'd add some tests:

```
// return error code
int my_strcpy(char* dest, const char* src, size_t max_size) {
  assert(dest && src && max_size && max_size < INT_MAX); // Validate arguments.
  //                                         v-- use int here --v
  int len = snprintf(dest, max_size, "%.*s", (int) (max_size - 1), src);
  return (len < 0 || (unsigned) len >= max_size);
}
```

---

I suspect `sprintf(dest, "%.*s", max_size - 1, src);` is sufficient too, expect it lacks detection of an overly long `src`.

---

Of course one could use something like

```
void my_strcpy(char* restrict dest, const char* restrict src, size_t size) {
  if (dest && src && size) {
    while (--size > 0 && *src) {
      *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    *dest = 0;
  }
}
```

`restrict` here implies `src/dest` do not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not completely safe for multiple reasons:

- The precision argument for `snprintf` `%.*s` specifier must be cast as an `int`. If `size_t` has a different size on your target system, the behavior is undefined. You should use a cast `(int)(max_size - 1)`.
- Your approach will fail if `max_size > INT_MAX` even with a cast.
- If `max_size == 0`, `snprintf()` might still read bytes from `src`, which might cause undefined behavior especially if the source string is not null terminated.
- If the source string is not correctly encoded according to the currently selected locale, `snprintf` might stop the copy and return -1, leaving the destination without a null terminator.

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve:

> *I use this way to copy strings knowing a max size to not go over but some of these strings don't end with a null terminator*

Is `max_size` a maximum number of bytes to copy as for `strncat` or the length of the destination array including space for the null terminator as for `snprintf`?

What strings do not have a null terminator? the source strings or the resulting contents of the destination array?

As coded, the argument `max_size` is the length of the destination array, including the null terminator.

To avoid the above issues, here are some standalone alternatives:

A truncating version that is very easy to use as

```
char array[SIZE];
my_strcpy_trunc(array, sizeof array, source);
```

```
// copy source string to an array of length size
// truncate contents to fit in the destination array
// return 0 if successful and no truncation occurred
// return 1 if truncation occurred
// return 2 if src is NULL, destination set to an empty string
// return -1 if arguments are invalid, no copy occurred
int my_strcpy_trunc(char *dest, size_t size, const char *src) {
    if (dest && size) {
        if (src) {
            for (;;) {
                if ((*dest++ = *src++) == '\0')
                    return 0;  // success
                if (--size == 0) {
                    dest[-1] = '\0';
                    return 1;  // truncation occurred
                }
            }
        }
        *dest = '\0';
        return 2;  // src is null pointer
    } else {
        return -1; // invalid dest
    }
}
```

A limiting version similar to `strncat` where you assume the destination has at least `n+1` bytes available, a less safe approach IMHO:

```
// copy source string up to a maximum of n bytes and set the null terminator to an array of length size
// return 0 if successful
// return 1 if successful and src length larger than n
// return 2 if src is NULL, destination set to an empty string
// return -1 if arguments are invalid, no copy occurred
int my_strcpy_limit(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n) {
    if (dest) {
        if (src) {
            while (n --> 0) {
                if ((*dest++ = *src++) == '\0')
                    return 0;  // success
            }
            *dest = '\0';
            return *src ? 1 : 0;
        }
        *dest = '\0';
        return 2;  // src is null pointer
    } else {
        return -1; // invalid dest
    }
}
```